# ¿Como obtengo el valor en entero de un select con Angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular7, angular6

Tengo mi formulario en `HTML` así:

```html
<div class="col-4">
    <label class="form-group my-1">Etnia</label>
    <select class="custom-select custom-select form-control" name="etniadId" [(ngModel)]="user.etniadId" id="etniadId">
        <option value="">Seleccione</option>
        <option *ngFor="let etnia of etnias" [value]="etnia.id">{{ etnia.name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Y esto es lo que tengo en el **archivo.ts**

```
user: User = {
   etniaId: null
}
```

Bueno hasta ahí va bien todo, pero quiero obtener el número o ID de manera que el `JSON` que envío sea entero y no como cadena.

Así es como me sale

```
etniadId: "7"
```

Pero quiero que salga así

```
etniaId: 7
```

Agradecería un montón que me colaboraran y dijeran como puedo solucionarlo

Comment: pues cuando envias los datos puedes parsearlo a number `parseInt(user.etniaId)`. No hay otra manera

Comment: tiene que existir una mejor manera :(

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasarlo a integer con `parseInt(user.etniaId, 10)` o, la manera que me gusta más, anteponerle `+`:

```
+user.etniadId
```

Si le dieses un número numérico en la primera asignación:

```
user: User = {
   etniaId: 0;
}
```

Y controlases que el 0 (o usar -1 en el caso que 0 sea un valor válido para ese campo) es que no está definido creo que ya no tendrías que hacer dicha conversión.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera. Quitar el doble binding y escuchar el `ngModelChange` y transformar el dato como quieras.

```
<div class="col-4">
    <label class="form-group my-1">Etnia</label>
    <select class="custom-select custom-select form-control" name="etniadId" [ngModel]="user.etniadId" (ngModelChange)="etniaChange($event)" id="etniadId">
        <option value="">Seleccione</option>
        <option *ngFor="let etnia of etnias" [value]="etnia.id">{{ etnia.name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
etniaChange(value: string) {
   if (value) {
     user.etniadId = +value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Amigo eso era lo que quería... eres un crack

Comment: @Torr amigo pues acepta la respuesta :)

Comment: oye, y.... ¿ese mismo lo puedo para convertir fechas como desee o no es recomendable ?

Comment: En principio no hay problema en usarlo, al fin al cabo, estas escuchando los cambios en un input.